Blank page on form submit of ASP.NET web application with validation failure
On submission of a form on my web application I am being directed to a blank page. When the details are input correctly the timecard is updated correctly. Similarly if I cancel out of the form I am redirected back with no changes being made. I have validation in place to ensure a time is input and a comment. However, when I leave the comment field blank I am being directed to a blank page. This did work previsouly I have been tidying up loose ends and I can't understand why it's no longer working.
This is the timecard entity
  public class TimeCard
    {
        // set by database
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime ClockIn { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;

        public DateTime ClockOut { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;

        public bool IsIn { get; set; }
        public bool Sickness { get; set; }
        public bool Holiday { get; set; }

       // used to add multple days of holidays at a time
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime HolidayStartDate { get; set; }

    
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime HolidayEndDate { get; set; }  // 
    

        // not always required, only for creates and edits of timecards
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string Comment { get; set; }



        // timecard is owned by user (employee)
        public int UserId { get; set; } // foreign key
        public User User { get; set; } // navigation property
    }

}

This is the edit view page
@model TimeCard

<h3 class="Form-heading">Edit TimeCard</h3>

<form asp-action="EditTimeCard" method="post" onsubmit="combineDateTime()">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />

    <!-- Hidden fields to hold the combined DateTime values -->
    <input type="hidden" id="ClockIn" asp-for="ClockIn" />
    <input type="hidden" id="ClockOut" asp-for="ClockOut" />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group edit-form">
                <label class="form-label"><i class="bi bi-calendar-plus-fill"></i>Date</label>
                <input type="date" id="ClockInDate" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group edit-form">
                <label class="form-label"><i class="bi bi-alarm-fill"></i>Clock In Time</label>
                <input type="time" id="ClockInTime" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group edit-form">
                <label class="form-label"><i class="bi bi-alarm-fill"></i>Clock Out Time</label>
                <input type="time" id="ClockOutTime" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group edit-form">
        <label asp-for="Comment" class="form-label">Comment</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Comment" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Comment" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn1">Edit TimeCard</button>
    <a class="cancel-btn" asp-controller="User" asp-action="TimeCardLog" asp-route-id="@Model.User.Id">Cancel</a>
</form>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        // Pre-fill date and time fields with existing values
        var clockIn = new Date('@Model.ClockIn.ToString("o")');
        var clockOut = new Date('@Model.ClockOut.ToString("o")');

        document.getElementById('ClockInDate').value = clockIn.toISOString().split('T')[0];
        document.getElementById('ClockInTime').value = clockIn.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].substring(0, 5);
        document.getElementById('ClockOutTime').value = clockOut.toTimeString().split(' ')[0].substring(0, 5);
    });

    function combineDateTime() {
        var clockInDate = document.getElementById('ClockInDate').value;
        var clockInTime = document.getElementById('ClockInTime').value;
        var clockOutTime = document.getElementById('ClockOutTime').value;

        // Combine date and time for Clock In
        var clockInDateTime = clockInDate + 'T' + clockInTime;
        document.getElementById('ClockIn').value = clockInDateTime;

        // Combine date and time for Clock Out
        var clockOutDateTime = clockInDate + 'T' + clockOutTime;
        document.getElementById('ClockOut').value = clockOutDateTime;
    }
</script>



And finally this is the controller for the edit function
  // GET: /User/EditTimeCard/{id}
    [Authorize(Roles = "manager, admin")]
    public IActionResult EditTimeCard(int id)
    {
        // Retrieve the timecard by its Id
        var timeCard = _tcSvc.GetTimeCard(id);

        if (timeCard == null)
        {
            Alert($"TimeCard not found", AlertType.warning);
            return RedirectToAction("TimeCardLog", new { id = timeCard.UserId }); // Redirect to timecard log if not found
        }

        return View(timeCard);
    }

    // POST: /User/EditTimeCard/{id}
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult EditTimeCard(int id, TimeCard model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Comment))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Comment", "Comment cannot be left blank. Please enter reason for edit");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Update the timecard using the service method
            var updatedTimeCard = _tcSvc.UpdateTimeCard(id, model.ClockIn, model.ClockOut, model.Comment);

            if (updatedTimeCard != null)
            {
                Alert("TimeCard updated successfully", AlertType.success);
                return RedirectToAction("TimeCardLog", new { id = updatedTimeCard.UserId }); // Redirect to timecard log after successful update
            }
            else
            {
                Alert("TimeCard could not be updated", AlertType.warning);
            }
        }

        // If ModelState is invalid, return to the edit view with validation errors
        return View(model);
    }

I have gone through my github commits and honeslty can't see anything that I have changed to these parts of the code for it to have caused this issue.
I added this script as well but no luck! I have the samek kind of form for adding a timecard but the validation does show up for it. Any insight at all would be great!!
@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}



If you getting a blank page when the comment is left empty, ensure that the post action method returns a same view with error and please share if you are getting any errors in console

So my post action is returning the model view when the model state is not valid. I have added this to teh cancel button shown in the edit timecard view page asp-route-id="@(Model.User != null ? Model.User.Id : 0)" as it was coming up a null exception error. Even though Model.User.Id was definitely not null! Inputing this allows for the validation to appear, however if I decided to cancel after 'submitting' the false form once it reverts the Model.User to null and thus 0. Its a semi-solution but doesnt fix the problem.

Due to the @Model.User.Id does not have value, so it will receive NullReferenceException when the action post back to render the view. You can set breakpoint in visual studio to check the post method if the model.User is null or not.
A simple way is to add the hidden input to store the value:
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.User.Id" />

Another way is to set the value for model.User in the backend:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditTimeCard(int id, TimeCard model)
{
     var oldTimeCard  = _tcSvc.GetTimeCard(id);
     model.User = oldTimeCard.User;
     //do your stuff...
}

